# One KafkaTemplate vs multiple KafkaTemplates

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

What is the recommended way to define `KafkaTemplate` when there are several different types of messages to send? Use just one `KafkaTemplate` for all messages (with `Object`) or define each `KafkaTemplate` for every type of messages?

One template `KafkaTemplate` with `Object`:

```
// Object
@Bean
ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfiguration());
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

Or multiple `KafkaTemplate`:

```
// Address
@Bean
ProducerFactory<String, Address> addressProducerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfiguration());
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Address> addressKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(addressProducerFactory());
}

// Person
@Bean
ProducerFactory<String, Person> personProducerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfiguration());
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Person> personPafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(personProducerFactory());
}
```

In the latter example `ProducerFactory` beans are also usually defined for every message type, which adds extra code. Do we really need them? It is ok just use a constructor, like this:

```
// Address
@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Address> addressKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfiguration()));
}

// Person
@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Person> personPafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfiguration()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic type on `KafakTemplate` is really only important for `receive()` operations.

`<Object, Object>` is fine for most cases (i.e. not using receive).

However, Spring Boot auto configures a template with `<?, ?>` this allows you to inject it in multiple places with whatever generics you want. There is no need to specify multiple template beans.

Same thing with the producer and consumer factories.

Comment: Thx. So kafka template with `<Object, Object>` is considered as a best practice? Having just one kafka template with `<Object, Object>` theoretically leads to the techincal possibility to send a message with a not a proper type (say different topics imply different message types). Is it ok?

Comment: It's best practice if the serializer can handle any Object (e.g. Json). If the serializer is strongly typed, then the template should be too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you conclude your decision. You should go with a single generic KafkaTemplate<String, Object> even if the producer is publishing different types of value/data on multiple topics.

It is similar to having a JdbcTemplate in an application specific to a database and independent of a table. For one database, we keep one JdbcTemplate until an application connects to multiple databases.